# Product of Hermitian operators

Tags: adjoint-operators, sturm-liouville

I am having trouble to proof that the product of two hermitian operators is hermitian iff they commute. Given the definition of hermitianity:

D is hermitian if it satisfy $$\int f^*(x)Dg(x)dx=\int g(x)D^*f^*(x)dx;$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write this out in terms of inner products; I will use hats to display operators.

Take two Hermetian operators $\hat{R}, \hat{S}$. Then, by defnition, the operators are Hermetian if
\begin{align*}
\langle\hat{R}f,g \rangle &= \langle f, \hat{R}g\rangle \label{1} \tag{*}\\
\langle \hat{S} f, g \rangle &= \langle f ,\hat{S} g \rangle \label{2} \tag{**}
\end{align*}
see for example https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hermitian_operator or https://en.universaldenker.org/lessons/1167.
Now we can do the same for the product of the two. The product is Hermetian iff, for all functions $f,g$ we have
\begin{align*}
\langle \hat{R}\hat{S} f, g \rangle &= \langle f, \hat{R}\hat{S} g \rangle \label{3} \tag{***}\\
\iff \langle \hat{R} (\hat{S} f), g \rangle &= \langle f, \hat{R} (\hat{S} g) \rangle 
\end{align*}
Now let $h = \hat{S}f$, and $j = \hat{S}g$.
$$
\langle \hat{R} h,g \rangle = \langle f, \hat{R} j \rangle
$$
Then we can use the hermetian properties (which apply to all functions) \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} which state that this is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
\langle h, \hat{R}g \rangle &= \langle\hat{R} f, j \rangle\\
\iff \langle \hat{S}f, \hat{R}g \rangle &= \langle \hat{R}f, \hat{S} g\rangle \\
\end{align*}
In a similar way, by letting $\hat{R} g = r, \hat{S}g = s$ we can rewrite this as:
\begin{align*}
\langle \hat{S} f, r \rangle = \langle \hat{R} f, s \rangle
\end{align*}
to wich we can apply \eqref{1},\eqref{2} to get:
\begin{align*}
\langle f, \hat{S} r \rangle &= \langle f, \hat{R} s \rangle \\
\iff \langle f, \hat{S} \hat{R}g \rangle &= \langle f, \hat{R} \hat{S} g \rangle \label{4} \tag{****}
\end{align*}
and from \eqref{4} it follows that, for all functions $g$ we must have that
\begin{align*}
\hat{R} \hat{S} g &= \hat{S} \hat{R} g \\
\iff \hat{R} \hat{S} &= \hat{S} \hat{R}
\end{align*}
thus the operators commute (notice that we've only used equivalences ($\iff$) in the proof).

To finish the proof for the integrals $\int f^{*}(x) D g(x) dx = \int g(x) D^{*} f^{*}(x) dx$ you only need to realise that this is just a special case of an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on a vector space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Examples